# How to use VBScript in Powerdesigner?

Tags: vbscript, sybase, powerbuilder

In Powerdesign would like to create a VBscript to rename/reform the following names in powerdesigner- Conceptural or Physical model

**Alternative/Unique Key Name:**

> > *UQ {table_name} {tablecolumnname}* ///////
> >     **Example** = UQ_Account_AccountNumber

**Relationship Name:**

> > *FK_{table_name}_{reference_table_name}_{reference_column_name}*
> >     //////**Example** = FK_Account_AccountPhone_HomePhoneID

Problem is, **how do I get the "table_column_name" and "reference_column_name"?**

Comment: Useful: http://blogs.conchango.com/danperrin/archive/2008/07/11/sybase-powerdesigner-scripting.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something I used to rename the 'friendly' names, plus the constraint names of all my references.  Maybe it will help you out.

```
Option Explicit
ValidationMode  = True
InteractiveMode = im_Batch

Dim mdl 
Set mdl = ActiveModel
If (mdl Is Nothing) Then
   MsgBox "There is no current Model"
ElseIf Not mdl.IsKindOf(PdPDM.cls_Model) Then
   MsgBox "The current model is not a Physical Data model."
Else
   ProcessFolder mdl
End If

Private sub ProcessFolder(folder)
   Dim Tab, Key, Rel
   for each Rel in Folder.References
      Rel.ForeignKeyConstraintName = "FK_" + UCASE(Rel.ParentTable.Name) + "_" + UCASE(Rel.ParentKeyColumnList) + "_" + UCASE(Rel.ChildTable.Name) + "_" + UCASE(Rel.ForeignKeyColumnList)
      Rel.Name = "FK_" + UCASE(Rel.ParentTable.Name) + "_" + UCASE(Rel.ParentKeyColumnList) + "_" + UCASE(Rel.ChildTable.Name) + "_" + UCASE(Rel.ForeignKeyColumnList)
   next
end sub
```